# moderncv - modify size of blank spaces

Tags: spacing, moderncv

I'm trying to find a way to modify the `moderncv` LaTeX "library" (dk if library is the right word).
As shown on the picture below, I want the space 1 & 2 to be reduced by half.

I'm new in LaTeX, it's awesome btw, sorry if this is a stupid question.

[image]

Comment: May I ask why you want to do this? I think the space around the picture is typografical okay.

Comment: I asked my mom "what do you think about my new CV ?" She told me "It's great but the space [1 & 2] are too big".

Comment: My interest in the answer to this question is simply that a proposal requires a 2-page CV and so removal of unnecessary white space is useful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer depends on the style used. Assuming the `casual` style, you can redefine `\makecvtitle` in the following way (modified lines are signaled with `% NEW`; feel free to change the lengths used according to your needs):

```
\documentclass{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{casual}
\moderncvcolor{blue}

\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}
\photo{ctanlion}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\makecvtitle}{%
  \recomputecvlengths%
  \vspace*{-3em} % NEW
  \makecvfooter%
  \newbox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}%
  \savebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}{%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@photo}}%
      {}%
      {%
       \setlength\fboxrule{\@photoframewidth}%
       \ifdim\@photoframewidth=0pt%
         \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\fi%
       {\color{color1}\framebox{\includegraphics[width=\@photowidth]{\@photo}}}}}%
  \usebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}%
  % name
  \@initializelength{\makecvtitlepicturewidth}%
  \settowidth{\makecvtitlepicturewidth}{\usebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}}%
  \parbox[b]{\textwidth-\makecvtitlepicturewidth}{%
    \raggedleft\namefont{\color{color2!50}\@firstname} {\color{color2}\@familyname}}\\[-.35em]% alternate design: \MakeLowercase and no space
  {\color{color2!50}\rule{\textwidth}{.25ex}}%
  % optional title
  \ifthenelse{\equal{\@title}{}}{}{\\[1.25em]\null\hfill\titlestyle{\@title}}\\[0em]% NEW original 2.5em
  \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@quote}}%
    {}%
    {{\null\hfill\begin{minipage}{\quotewidth}\centering\quotestyle{\@quote}\end{minipage}\hfill\null\\[2.5em]}}%
  \par}% to avoid weird spacing bug at the first section if no blank line is left after \maketitle
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\makecvtitle
\section{Test Section}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Woaw ! Thank you very much ! I try this in 30min and let you know if it works

Answer (score 28):

If you are new to LaTeX and don't need the flexibility offered by Gonzalo's solution (that enables you to modify anything you want in the header), you could simply put this

```
\usepackage[scale=0.8,top=2cm]{geometry}
```

in you preamble (or modify a line looking like this one already there). The `scale=0.8` ensures that the margins are such that 80% of the page is reserved for the total body (change `0.8` to whatever you like between `0.0` and `1.0`), while `top=2cm` forces the top margin to be exactly `2cm` (again, change this to whatever you like).

For the space after the header, simply put

```
\vspace*{-5mm}
```

right after `\maketitle`. This produces a negative vertical space of `5mm`, or any other length you specify, i.e. it moves the following text back `5mm` to the top. You can also use this trick before a `\section` if you want to reduce the space between sections.

Comment: Thank you a lot !
I picked the @Gonzalo Medina as it was more complete (and I had to choose only one :x) but your answer is also exactly what I needed

Comment: This answer is exactly what I was looking for. Gonzalo's answer is more flexible, but may fall out of sync (if it hasn't already) with future updates to ModernCV.