# ModernCV classic style, change space below title

Tags: spacing, moderncv

I found [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82861/moderncv-modify-size-of-blank-spaces) post in the forums, and I want to do exactly the same but for moderncv's "classic" style.

I am pretty new to LaTeX and all the maketitle thing makes me dizzy, I tried to understand it a little but I didn't achieve much.

How would you do that?

Comment: [My answer there](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/82871/10102) is valid for any style.

Comment: @Xavier actually yes! Itried before but did't work, don't know why. post your answer as answer if you want, I'll mark it as correct!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[My answer there](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/82871/10102) is valid for any style. In short, use something like

```
\usepackage[scale=0.8,top=2cm]{geometry}
```

in you preamble for the page margins, and put

```
\vspace*{-5mm}
```

right after `\maketitle`.

Comment: as I already had the `geometry` package, `\vspace*{-5mm}` was enough for me, even did `\vspace*{-15mm}`