# moderncv - modify white space within title

Tags: moderncv, white-space

I have looked at similar problems on this sit namely [moderncv - modify size of blank spaces](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82861/moderncv-modify-size-of-blank-spaces/82871#82871) and [ModernCV classic style, change space below title](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96728/moderncv-classic-style-change-space-below-title) but these relate to white space below the title itself and I am trying to reduce the white space within the title.

[image]

I instead would like to try and just slightly decrease the what space between the address and the socials as I think it would looks slightly better. I have tried going into the moderncv.cls files and moderncvstylebanking.sty files and adding some negative \vspace{} but to no avail. Does anyone know how I might go about this.

Thanks in advance

MWE:

```
\documentclass[sans]{moderncv}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}

\moderncvstyle{banking}

\moderncvcolor{blue}

\usepackage{geometry} 
\geometry{
 a4paper,
 total={170mm,257mm},
 left=10mm,
 right=10mm,
 top=7.5mm,
 bottom=7.5mm,
 }

\firstname{John}

\familyname{Doe}

\title{Curriculum Vitae}   

\address{X something road Road}{London}{UK}

\mobile{+44~1234~567~890} 
                        
\email{email@gmail.com}  

\social[linkedin]{john-doe}

\social[github]{johndoe}                               

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't get nearly that large a gap when I compile your sample document—adding just `\documentclass[sans]{moderncv}` which you left out. Is there anything else missing from your code?

Comment: There were a few lines which I accidentally left out, I have now added them but removing them does not change that distance

Comment: maybe I should redownload the .cls and .sty files if your compilation is fine

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the issue but I don't think I have dealt with the underlying issue so if anyone can make sense of it please do.

I used TexPad and a part of that, for ease I use the Built-in TexpadTex Typesetter, and for some reason this is where the issue lies. I know very little about different typesetters but I would have thought they all compile the TeX in possibly different way but always arrive at the same end product. However **using the Typeset Engine as 'pdfLaTeX' I was able to fix** this issue with the game.

TL:DR - I believe Built-in TexpadTex Typesetter causes this issue.

Comment: So the solution was using pfdfLatex? If so I suggest to mark and highlight this term using Ctrl+k .