# Configure CV in LyX

Tags: spacing, lyx, moderncv, document-configuration

I would like to ask help in configuring my CV in LyX. I am using moderncv style with LyX in Ubuntu 12.04.

I shall say that I have found a close solution to my problem in this post on [blank spaces](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82861/moderncv-modify-size-of-blank-spaces), but cannot apply it directly as I am using LyX.  Then I also found another post in the [LyX wiki](http://wiki.lyx.org/Examples/ModernCVClassIssues), and followed it in order to modify the style files.  However, this is not a complete solution as I don't see a corresponding command in the style file.

My first question is if there are commands in the style file that I can change in order to modify the spacings as described in the first post.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you want to do the same changes as described in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82861/moderncv-modify-size-of-blank-spaces? Why can't you use Gonzalo's answer from that question? Should just be a matter of copying everything between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` to the LaTeX preamble of your LyX file.