# How can I delete spacing?

Tags: spacing, moderncv

How can I delete the spacing shown in the following image:

[image]

And here is my code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} % Font sizes: 10, 11, or 12; paper sizes: a4paper, letterpaper, a5paper, legalpaper, executivepaper or landscape; font families: sans or roman

\moderncvstyle{casual} % CV theme - options include: 'casual' (default), 'classic', 'oldstyle' and 'banking'
\moderncvcolor{blue} % CV color - options include: 'blue' (default), 'orange', 'green', 'red', 'purple', 'grey' and 'black'

\usepackage{lipsum} % Used for inserting dummy 'Lorem ipsum' text into the template
\usepackage[top=1.1cm, bottom=1.5cm, left=2cm, right=2cm]{geometry}
%\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry} % Reduce document margins
%\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm} % Uncomment to change the width of the dates column
%\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{10cm} % For the 'classic' style, uncomment to adjust the width of the space allocated to your name




%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   NAME AND CONTACT INFORMATION SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\firstname{Mehmet} % Your first name
\familyname{DEMIR} % Your last name

% All information in this block is optional, comment out any lines you don't need
\title{Étudiant en réseaux et télécommunications}
\address{50, rue de la Paix}{77270 Villeparisis}
\phone{06 52 42 28 65}
\email{demir.mehmet90@gmail.com}
\extrainfo{23 ans}
%\homepage{staff.org.edu/~jsmith}{staff.org.edu/$\sim$jsmith} % The first argument is the url for the clickable link, the second argument is the url displayed in the template - this allows special characters to be displayed such as the tilde in this example
\extrainfo{Permis B / Véhiculé}
\photo[100pt][0.4pt]{pictures/picture} % The first bracket is the picture height, the second is the thickness of the frame around the picture (0pt for no frame)
\quote{Obtenir un contrat d'apprentissage d'une durée de trois ans en cycle ingénieur}


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle % Print the CV title

\section{Formations}
\cventry{2013 -- 2014}{Formation d'Ingénieurs}{Institut Galilée}{}{}{Spécialité Télécommunications et Réseaux}
\cventry{2010 -- 2013}{Diplôme Universitaire de Technologie}{I.U.T de Villetaneuse (Paris XIII)}{}{}{Spécialité Télécommunications et Réseaux}
\cventry{2010}{Baccalauréat Scientifique}{Lycée Gérard de Nerval (Noisiel, 77186)}{}{}{Spécialité Physique-Chimie}

\section{Compétences}
\cvitem{Langages}{Java, HTML5/CSS3, Javascript, C/C++, PHP, SQL, Script Shell, XML}
\cvitem{Environnements}{Windows, Linux, Android}
\cvitem{Réseaux}{Mise en places des architectures LAN / WLAN}
\cvitem{}{Principe d'interconnexion de réseaux TCP/ IP}
\cvitem{}{Paramétrage de routeurs CISCO}
\cvitem{}{Mise en place d'outils réseaux sur un serveur Linux : DHCP, VPN, firewall (iptables) et proxy}
\cvitem{}{Réseaux locaux, Ethernet}
\cvitem{Télécoms}{Configuration PABX, VoIP}
\cvitem{}{Fibre optique}
\cvitem{Langues}{\textbf{Anglais}\hspace{6.32cm}Bon niveau (\textbf{950} au dernier \textbf{TOEIC})}
\cvitem{}{Turc\hspace{6.972cm}Bilingue}
\cvitem{}{Espagnol\hspace{6.215cm}Débutant}
\cvitem{Logiciels}{Microsoft Office, Open Office}

\section{Expériences professionnelles}

\cventry{Mars 2012\\\`a  Aujourd'hui}{Auto-entrepreneur}{}{}{}{Gestion de Oues Peinture, entreprise spécialisée dans la peinture et travaux de rénovation.\newline{}}

\cventry{Avril 2013\\\`a Juin 2013}{Stage de fin d'études}{University of Bergen}{Norv\`ege}{}{Développement d'une application mobile Android pour contr\^oler une prise de courant GSM.\newline{}}

\cventry{2006 - 2012}{Travailleur saisonnier}{SBR Décoration}{entreprise de B.T.P}{}{
\begin{itemize}%
\item Préparation de commandes, factures et devis,
\item Elaboration de l'emploi du temps des salariés,
\item Gestion des courriers de l'Assurance Retraite et de l'URSSAF.\newline{}
\end{itemize}}

\section{Centres d'intérêt}
\cvitem{Intérêts}{Association << Entraide Scolaire Amicale >>}
\cvitem{Sport}{Football en salle, musculation}
\cvitem{Cinéma}{Films et séries anglophones en version originale}


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   LANGUAGES SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\section{Languages}

\cvitemwithcomment{English}{Mothertongue}{}
\cvitemwithcomment{Spanish}{Intermediate}{Conversationally fluent}
\cvitemwithcomment{Dutch}{Basic}{Basic words and phrases only}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\vspace*{-1cm}` but don't make it too cramped.

Comment: @SeanAllred I tried this but it didn't work, maybe you can tell me in which line I have to add this vspace attribute please?

Comment: @SeanAllred beacause when I use it, it reduces the margin between my photo and the bottom of the file...

Comment: @forgive90: Add that `\vspace{<len>}` (where you specify a convenient length `<len>`) just after `\moderncvtitle`.

Comment: @Werner like you can see here, I don't have \moderncvtitle attribute...

Comment: I think Werner meant after `\makecvtitle`

Comment: @SeanAllred Like I said earlier, it changes only the margin between the top of my file & the top of my photo... not the space I showed you :s

Comment: I was wrong using it, finally I fixed it, thank you :))

Comment: @forgive90: [This is how you should use it](http://i.stack.imgur.com/BSWGY.png).

Comment: This answer is very good for controlling all dimensions: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/82868/31034

Answer (score 7):

### Update (`moderncv` v2.0)

With `moderncv` v2.0, the command to be patched is no more `\makecvtitle` but `\makecvhead`, so the correct patch for this version is

```
  \patchcmd{\makecvhead}%
  {\hfill\null\\[2.5em]}%
  {\hfill\null\\[0em]}%
  {}%
  {}%
```

---

### Original answer (works with older versions of `moderncv`)

The `casual` style adds a vertical spacing of `2.5em` after the `\quote`.

One way to reduce that spacing is to "patch" the command `\makecvtitle`. For example you can set it to `0em`.

To do that, add the following lines in your preamble:

```
  \patchcmd{\makecvtitle}%
  {\hfill\null\\[2.5em]}%
  {\hfill\null\\[0em]}%
  {}%
  {}%
```

You can adjust `0em` to your needs (even a negative value).

Thus, the following MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} % Font sizes: 10, 11, or 12; paper sizes: a4paper, letterpaper, a5paper, legalpaper, executivepaper or landscape; font families: sans or roman

\moderncvstyle{casual} % CV theme - options include: 'casual' (default), 'classic', 'oldstyle' and 'banking'
\moderncvcolor{blue} % CV color - options include: 'blue' (default), 'orange', 'green', 'red', 'purple', 'grey' and 'black'

\patchcmd{\makecvtitle}%
  {\hfill\null\\[2.5em]}%
  {\hfill\null\\[0em]}%
  {}%
  {}%

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{lipsum} % Used for inserting dummy 'Lorem ipsum' text into the template
\usepackage[top=1.1cm, bottom=1.5cm, left=2cm, right=2cm]{geometry}
%\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry} % Reduce document margins
%\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm} % Uncomment to change the width of the dates column
%\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{10cm} % For the 'classic' style, uncomment to adjust the width of the space allocated to your name




%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   NAME AND CONTACT INFORMATION SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\firstname{Mehmet} % Your first name
\familyname{DEMIR} % Your last name

% All information in this block is optional, comment out any lines you don't need
\title{Étudiant en réseaux et télécommunications}
\address{50, rue de la Paix}{77270 Villeparisis}
\phone{06 52 42 28 65}
\email{demir.mehmet90@gmail.com}
\extrainfo{23 ans}
%\homepage{staff.org.edu/~jsmith}{staff.org.edu/$\sim$jsmith} % The first argument is the url for the clickable link, the second argument is the url displayed in the template - this allows special characters to be displayed such as the tilde in this example
\extrainfo{Permis B / Véhiculé}
\photo[100pt][0.4pt]{picture} % The first bracket is the picture height, the second is the thickness of the frame around the picture (0pt for no frame)
\quote{Obtenir un contrat d'apprentissage d'une durée de trois ans en cycle ingénieur}


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle % Print the CV title

\section{Formations}
\cventry{2013 -- 2014}{Formation d'Ingénieurs}{Institut Galilée}{}{}{Spécialité Télécommunications et Réseaux}
\cventry{2010 -- 2013}{Diplôme Universitaire de Technologie}{I.U.T de Villetaneuse (Paris XIII)}{}{}{Spécialité Télécommunications et Réseaux}
\cventry{2010}{Baccalauréat Scientifique}{Lycée Gérard de Nerval (Noisiel, 77186)}{}{}{Spécialité Physique-Chimie}

\section{Compétences}
\cvitem{Langages}{Java, HTML5/CSS3, Javascript, C/C++, PHP, SQL, Script Shell, XML}
\cvitem{Environnements}{Windows, Linux, Android}
\cvitem{Réseaux}{Mise en places des architectures LAN / WLAN}
\cvitem{}{Principe d'interconnexion de réseaux TCP/ IP}
\cvitem{}{Paramétrage de routeurs CISCO}
\cvitem{}{Mise en place d'outils réseaux sur un serveur Linux : DHCP, VPN, firewall (iptables) et proxy}
\cvitem{}{Réseaux locaux, Ethernet}
\cvitem{Télécoms}{Configuration PABX, VoIP}
\cvitem{}{Fibre optique}
\cvitem{Langues}{\textbf{Anglais}\hspace{6.32cm}Bon niveau (\textbf{950} au dernier \textbf{TOEIC})}
\cvitem{}{Turc\hspace{6.972cm}Bilingue}
\cvitem{}{Espagnol\hspace{6.215cm}Débutant}
\cvitem{Logiciels}{Microsoft Office, Open Office}

\section{Expériences professionnelles}

\cventry{Mars 2012\\\`a  Aujourd'hui}{Auto-entrepreneur}{}{}{}{Gestion de Oues Peinture, entreprise spécialisée dans la peinture et travaux de rénovation.\newline{}}

\cventry{Avril 2013\\\`a Juin 2013}{Stage de fin d'études}{University of Bergen}{Norv\`ege}{}{Développement d'une application mobile Android pour contr\^oler une prise de courant GSM.\newline{}}

\cventry{2006 - 2012}{Travailleur saisonnier}{SBR Décoration}{entreprise de B.T.P}{}{
\begin{itemize}%
\item Préparation de commandes, factures et devis,
\item Elaboration de l'emploi du temps des salariés,
\item Gestion des courriers de l'Assurance Retraite et de l'URSSAF.\newline{}
\end{itemize}}

\section{Centres d'intérêt}
\cvitem{Intérêts}{Association << Entraide Scolaire Amicale >>}
\cvitem{Sport}{Football en salle, musculation}
\cvitem{Cinéma}{Films et séries anglophones en version originale}


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   LANGUAGES SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\section{Languages}

\cvitemwithcomment{English}{Mothertongue}{}
\cvitemwithcomment{Spanish}{Intermediate}{Conversationally fluent}
\cvitemwithcomment{Dutch}{Basic}{Basic words and phrases only}

\end{document}
```

yields the following result:

[image]